# How do I link simply to the directory my RSS XML file is in, not the actual file?

Tags: .htaccess, rss

Really stupid question here, as nothing I try is working. I've got my xml file set up fine, and it's validated fine, but I can't get the whole thing to work via a link to the directory the xml file is in. It only works when I specify the actual file. When I link simply to the directory, and I click the RSS image file, it sends me to a listing of the file(s) in the directory. If I then click on the xml file link, then I get sent to the feed subscription page (via Firefox). How do I link simply to the directory with my xml file in it? Do I have to edit my .htaccess file? Here's what I've got (my files are HTML5):

```
    <link rel="alternate" href="/rss" title="RSS feed" type="application/rss+xml">
```

and I've also tried to see if doing this will change what happens when I click on the image file, but it won't:

```
    <link rel="alternate" href="/rss/index.xml" title="RSS feed" type="application/rss+xml">
```

This works:

```
<a type="application/rss+xml" href="/rss/index.xml"><img src="/images/rss.png"></a>
```

This won't:

```
<a type="application/rss+xml" href="/rss"><img src="/images/rss.png"></a>
```

What stupid mistake am I missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to make `/rss` load the content in the file `/hosts/example/htdocs/rss/index.xml`?

Comment: @Quentin : Yes, exactly. A no-brainier when it comes to HTML files or PHP files, but which won't work with this XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

```
DirectoryIndex index.xml
```

Or possibly [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Sweet! That worked like a charm. Surprised none of those sites explaining how to manually code your own RSS feed mentioned it. (Although perhaps I should have known about it already.) Thanks again!